# Is there an opposite to an action listener in java so it performs a command when an action isn't happening?

Tags: java

I have made a basic chat application in java using eclipse. I am now starting to add extra features to it and am currently stuck on a feature that tells the user when the other person is typing, similar to whatsapp and facebook messenger.

currently i have an integer that records if the user is typing

```
public int typing = 0;
```

when it is 0 the user isn't typing when it is 1 they are (a boolean wouldn't work for some reason)

I have an action listener on the textbox that listens for a caret update and excecutes this code:

```
isTyping = 1;
String typing = ("t-");
client.send(typing.getBytes());
```

The server then relays this back to the other clients and when they recieve this message that gets sent if they are not typing it will make the someone is typing label appear.

What i would like is something to listen for when the caret is not updating to execute this code:

```
isTyping = 0;
String typing = ("n-");
client.send(typing.getBytes());
```

Is this possible or is there a way to make this work as i seem to need to listen for no carat update?

Comment: Do something, then when an event is triggered, *don't do that something*.

Comment: Run a periodic timer, which increments a counter. Clear the counter on a key press.  Fire an event when counter exceeds a limit.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest avoiding the listener and creating a thread:

The created thread checks the value of textbox and remembers the current value of the textbox in a loop. If the value hasn't changed since the last check, it means that the user is not typing. It is up to you to consider frequency of the check and maybe only a length of the value could be used for the check.

Answer (score 1):

Make a single “expiration” Timer that waits a short delay, and then executes your “not typing” action.  Whenever the text field’s document changes, restart the Timer, to ensure it only manages to execute when there is a lull in the user’s typing:

```
JTextField textField = /* ... */;

ActionListener idleSender = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        isTyping = false;
        client.send("n-".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
};

int delay = 2000;  // 2 seconds
final Timer sendTimer = new Timer(delay, idleSender);
sendTimer.setRepeats(false);
sendTimer.start();

textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        sendTimer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        sendTimer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        sendTimer.restart();
    }
});
```

Some notes:

- It is important to use javax.swing.Timer, *not* java.util.Timer.  The latter uses its own thread, while the former always executes its task on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.  Calling (almost) any AWT or Swing method on any thread other than the EDT is not allowed, and while violating that rule may not generate an exception, things tend to break intermittently and unpredictably.
- Using `typing.getBytes()` without passing an charset to getBytes() may cause data corruption on the other side.  It will convert bytes using the underlying system’s default charset, which may not be the same as the server’s default charset.  It is a good idea to use `"n-".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead.
- I don’t know what “a boolean wouldn’t work for some reason” actually means, but booleans work perfectly in all circumstances.  If you had a problem, you will be doing yourself a service by finding out what that problem is and fixing it, rather than writing peculiar code that sidesteps the issue, only to come back to it months later and wonder why you are using 0 and 1 in place of false and true.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a command while an action isn't happening isn't really possible, because it doesn't answer one crucial question - how often should it happen? *Always* isn't really an answer - that would require an infinite loop constantly executing, which will throttle your application as a whole.

That said, you can set up a timed delay for sending a notification that the person has stopped editing. In my mind it would count down (via thread sleep) towards 0 and refresh to a set (positive) amount whenever a key is pressed, but it could be the opposite as well (as AJ suggests in the comments).

```
public class NotificationSender {

  private boolean isEditing;
  private final Object isEditingLock;

  private DelayedTurnOffThread turnOffThread;
  private static final long MS_TO_OFF_NOTIFICATION = 1000;

  public NotificationSender() {
    isEditing = false;
    isEditingLock = new Object();
    turnOffThread = null;
  }

  private void sendEditingNotification(String newContent) {
    System.out.println("Editing, new content=" + newContent);
  }

  private void sendStopEditingNotification() {
    System.out.println("Editing stopped");
  }

  public boolean isEditing() {
    synchronized (isEditingLock) {
      return isEditing;
    }
  }

  public void doEdit(String newContent) {
    synchronized (isEditingLock) {
      isEditing = true;
      sendEditingNotification(newContent);

      if (turnOffThread != null) {
        turnOffThread.interrupt();
      }
      turnOffThread = new DelayedTurnOffThread();
      turnOffThread.start();
    }
  }

  private class DelayedTurnOffThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(MS_TO_OFF_NOTIFICATION);
        synchronized (isEditingLock) {
          isEditing = false;
          sendStopEditingNotification();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Do nothing - superceded by other turnoff thread
      }
    }
  }

  //
  //DEMO CODE BELOW
  //
  private static class NotificationDemo extends JFrame {

    private NotificationSender notificationSender;

    public NotificationDemo() {
      notificationSender = new NotificationSender();
      JTextField textField = new JTextField();
      getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
          notificationSender.doEdit(((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText() + e.getKeyChar());
        }

        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
      });

      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NotificationDemo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont understand how this detects the user is typing? do i still need to use an action listener and call this?

Comment: Precisely. Create an action listener that calls notificationSender.doEdit()

Comment: I have made everything static but i am unable to call doEdit(), what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Edited to be a runnable example. You can now paste this code into a fresh project and run it, it'll print as the notifications are sent.